# I cant back up mysql database with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

The main problem is when i try to backup database with:

```
mysqldump -u root -p foo > /home/backup/backup.foo_db.sql
```

i get the error:

```
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'database=foo'
```

and on the other hand when i just write

```
mysqldump
```

i get the same error.
here is my 'my.cnf' file:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[client]
database=foo
user=foouser
password=foopassword
default-character-set=utf8
```

Comment: please comment (database=foo) for my.cnf.
and try to dump of db

Comment: Is foo is the name of db or table?

Comment: @SubhashisPandey is that DB name but the issue is he defines DB name in my.cnf so getting this issue .

Comment: @SubhashisPandey if my.cnf created on user home-directory that time its works.

Comment: @RakeshGadhwal i commented it and now no database selected error raise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tealy

Please update your my.cnf file.

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[client]
#database=foo
#user=foouser
#password=foopassword
#default-character-set=utf8
```

and try to dunp using mysqldump.

Comment: i dont understand this time i cant connect django to mysql what is the purpose of this.

Comment: @tealy if you want mysqldump then you have to comment some parameters in my.cnf.

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'foo',
        'USER': 'foouser',
        'PASSWORD': 'foopassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

Comment: use this in django connections .